# GCD of Polynomial Roots.

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

I am sure there is an obvious answer, but suppose I have a monic polynomial with non-zero, integer coefficients given by

$$P(x) = x^n + a_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$$

Veita's Formulas state the roots are related to the constant term $a_0$ where

$$a_0 = (-1)^nr_1r_2\dots r_n$$

where repetition is allowed. Now suppose there exists a rational root $r_1$. Since the Rational Root Theorem states that all rational roots of a monic polynomial are integers, the root $r_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Does it follow that if $GCD(r_1, r_2r_3\dots r_n) = 1$, then for any other rational root, say WLOG $r_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, that $GCD(r_1, r_2) = 1$? I am assuming it does, but I am not fully sure.

Comment: Are you assuming all of the roots are rational?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley no, since it is just a general polynomial. That is what is holding me up. If they were, then it would be fairly straightforward just using the properties of the GCD.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes, it would have to be an integer since it is $a_0$ divided by the root $r_1$.

Comment: What do you mean by GCD for non-integers?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley There are only GCDs of integers in this post.

Comment: so why do vieta's formulas state 0=(−1)12…

Comment: By the linked dupe, $ f := \frac{P}{(x-r_1)(x-r_2)}\in \Bbb Q[x]\Rightarrow f\in\Bbb Z[x],\,$ so $\,f(0)=(-1)^n r_3\cdots r_n\in \Bbb Z,\,$ so $(r_1,r_2f(0))=1\Rightarrow (r_1,r_2)=1\,$ by [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20904/242).

Comment: The "linked dupe" contains the main argument indeed but cannot be called a dupe, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right: for all $s,p\in\Bbb Z$ such that the roots of $x^2-sx+p$ are roots of $P(x)$ (in particular for $s=r_1+r_2$ and $p=r_1r_2$ where $r_1,r_2\in\Bbb Z$),
[$$\frac{P(x)}{x^2-sx+p}\in\Bbb Z[x],$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73867/different-version-of-gausss-lemma/73911#73911)
in particular
$$t:=r_3\dots r_n=\pm\frac{a_0}p\in\Bbb Z.$$
Therefore, if $\gcd(r_1,r_2t)=1$ then $\gcd(r_1,r_2)=1.$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It's not clear precisely what argument you intend to prove that the polynomial quotient is in $\Bbb Z[x].\,$ Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Thank you, my (anyway uselessly "more general") statement was obviously false because I forgot to mention the unavoidable hypothesis I had in mind. I just inserted it. @BillDubuque

Comment: But it's still not clear precisely how you are deducing that the quotient is in $\color{#c00}{\Bbb Z}[x]\,$ vs. $\Bbb Q[x]\ $ (there are various ways to do so). $\  \ $

Comment: I took it for granted the OP knew that, and they seem to agree (in case they asked, I would have added details). I know there are various ways. My favorite proof is [Arturo's one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73911): very naturally, by Euclidean division. @BillDubuque

Comment: @Anne Where did the OP give any clue that they know that key fact?  I think it is essential to justify that claim in any answer since this is a point where many students stumble.

Comment: In their thanks. But, as already told, I was ready to answer if on the contrary they were missing this theorem. @BillDubuque

Comment: You can't assume that "thank you" means that the OP knows that there is a major gap in your answer, and knows how to close that gap. I don't understand why you don't want to fix your answer by closing this gap. Keep in mind also that answers are not only for the OP, so even if the OP did know these things, it does not mean this would be clear to other readers, esp. since there is no hint of such in the answer.

Comment: To me, "thank you" meant that the OP understood the answer, hence is aware of the theorem justifying the claim. I don't understand why you insist on the presence of a "gap" and the need to "fix" it. But I added a link, for "other readers".

Comment: The OP's "thank you" was posted at the time your (self-deemed) "obviously false" answer was active. Even I could not figure out precisely what that initial version was supposed to mean, so I highly doubt that the OP did. Again, I am quite perplexed why there seems to be resistance to clarifying the use of the key result. Even now it is still hidden in an obscure link on a formula. If the OP already knew this result then it is highly unlikely there would be any need to post the question since the proof is immediate after such.